# How do I write to the console in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, python-logging

Often when I am coding I just like to print little things (mostly the current value of variables) out to console. I don't see anything like this for Google App Engine, although I note that the Google App Engine Launcher does have a Log terminal. Is there any way to write to said Terminal, or to some other terminal, using Google App Engine?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You'll want to use the Python's standard `logging` module.

```
import logging

logging.info("hello")
logging.debug("hi") # this won't show up by default
```

To see calls to `logging.debug()` in the GoogleAppEngineLauncher Logs console, you have to first add the flag `--dev_appserver_log_level=debug` to your app. However, beware that you're going to see a lot of debug noise from the App Engine SDK itself. The [full set of levels](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2) are:

- `debug`
- `info`
- `warning`
- `error`
- `critical`

You can add the flag by double clicking the app and then dropping it into the **Extra Flags** field.

[image: Adding the --dev_appserver_log_level flag to your app in the GoogleAppEngineLauncher]

Comment: This was the most helpful response. It deserves notice

Comment: According to [this more recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22467787/346561), you should use the extra flag `--log_level=debug` instead of `--debug`.

Comment: I am trying to set my log level to warning to hide the INFO noise but its not working. Any Ideas?

Comment: turns out --dev_appserver_log_level=warning is the correct setting

Answer (score 32):

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/requests#Python_Logging 
and http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

You probably want to use something like:

```
logging.debug("value of my var is %s", str(var))
```

Comment: How can i do the same in java?

Comment: You'll most likely want to use logging.info() instead of logging.debug() because the default logging level in the GoogleAppEngineLauncher Logs console is such that you won't see any calls to logging.debug().

Comment: The first link to the Logging for Python GAE is broken. It should be updated to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/requests#Python_Logging

Answer (score 9):

@Manjoor

You can do the same thing in java.

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
// ...

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyServlet.class.getName());

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {

        log.info("An informational message.");

        log.warning("A warning message.");

        log.severe("An error message.");
    }
}
```

See "Logging" in http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a more recent version of the Python Development Server (releases > 1.7.6, or Mar 2013 and later), these seem to be the right steps to use:

1. Include the following in your script,

   `import logging
   logging.debug("something I want to log")`
2. And per [this docs page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver#New_Development_Server), set a flag by going to Edit > Application Settings > Launch Settings > Extra Command Line Flags, and adding,

   `--log_level=debug`

Answer (score 2):

You should also give FirePython a look.  It allows you to get server log messages in firebug.

http://appengine-cookbook.appspot.com/recipe/firepython-logger-console-inside-firebug/

Answer (score 1):

Check out my online Python interpreter running on Google App Engine on my website, [Learn Python](http://www.learnpython.org). It might be what you're looking for. Just use print repr(variable) on things you want to look at, and execute as many times as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I'm using the version 1.8.6 of GoogleAppEngineLauncher, you can use a flag to set the messages log level you want to see, for example for debug messages:

`--dev_appserver_log_level debug`

Use it instead of `--debug` (see @Christopher answer).

Answer (score 0):

GAE will capture standard error and print it to the console or to a log.

```
print >> sys.stderr, "Something to log."
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use log.setLevel(Level.ALL) to see messages**

The default message filtering level seems to be 'error'.  I didn't see any useful log messages until I used the setLevel() method to make the .info and .warning messages visible.

Text printed to System.out wasn't showing up either.  It seems to be interpreted as log.info() level messaages.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i am answering the question. The logging messages print to the AppEngine log rather than the terminal.

You can launch it
[by clicking on the logs button of the AppEngine Launcher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9wXa.png)

Answer (score 0):

[Using the `logging` module is good practice,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918493/in-python-why-use-logging-instead-of-print) but it's not required.

You can just do plain-old `print()`s to write to the Google App Engine Log Console.