# How do I write to the console in Google App Engine (JAVA)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am using eclipse and java sdk of app-engine. 
I found the link for same question

[here](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/a67752ac402bb21e)

and on stackoverflow

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727410/how-do-i-write-to-the-console-in-google-app-engine).

But both are for python.

Is there a way to do it in eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `java.lang.System` is whitelisted, so won't `java.lang.System.out.println(...)` work?

Comment: +1: Yes, according to the docs writing to stdout will be captured and logged at the INFO level.  Likewise, writing to stderr will be logged at the WARN level.

Comment: Is there somewhere in particular it needs to go? It wasn't working in the doPost() function I had.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [java.util.logging.Logger](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html) class.  See [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Logging) for examples and more information.

Comment: It does not print on console.

Comment: Strange, what level did you try to log at?  INFO level and higher should appear.  Writing to standard out is supposed to be logged by GAE to the logs at the INFO level in the Java runtime.

Comment: if you configure it properly, you can get the Logger to output to the console.