# How can i test a void function in python using pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I just started unit testing in python using pytest. Well, when I have a function with a return value, with the "assert" I can compare a certain value with the value that the function return.
But if I had a void function that returns nothing and does a print at the end, for example:

```
def function() -> None:
    number = randint(0, 4)

    if (number == 0):
       print("Number 0")

    elif (number == 1):
       print("Number 1")

    elif (number == 2):
       print("Number 2")

    elif (number == 3):
       print("Number 3")

    elif (number == 4):
       print("Number 4")
```

How can i test this simple function to get 100% code coverage?

One method I've found to test this function is to do a return of the value (instead of print) and print it later, and then use the assert. But I wanted to know if it was possible to avoid this and do a test directly on the print statemant.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect `sys.stdout` (the stream that `print` writes to) to a buffer and then examine or assert the contents of the buffer.

```
>>> import io
>>> import contextlib
>>> 
>>> def f():print('X')
... 
>>> buf = io.StringIO()
>>> with contextlib.redirect_stdout(buf):
...     f()
... 
>>> print(repr(buf.getvalue()))
'X\n'
>>> 
>>> buf.close()
```

(Recall that [print()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) appends the value of its `end` argument to the line, which defaults to `'\n'`).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a look at the plugin [pytest-mock](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/). It allows you to [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) collaborating objects of your code under test.

Consider the following code under test:

```
# production.py 

def say_hello() -> None:
    print('Hello World.')
```

you can easily mock this now with

```
# production_test.py
from production import say_hello

def test_greeting(mocker):
    # The "mocker" fixture is auto-magicall inserted by pytest, 
    # once the extenson 'pytest-mock' is installed
    printer = mocker.patch('builtins.print')
    say_hello()
    assert printer.call_count == 1
```

You can also assert the arguments the printer function was called with, etc. You will find a lot of details in their useful [documentation](https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html).

---

Now, consider you do not want to access the `printer`, but have a code with some undesirable side-effects (e.g. an operation takes forever, or the result is non-predictable (random).) Let's have another example, say

```
# deep_though.py

class DeepThought:
    #: Seven and a half million years in seconds
    SEVEN_HALF_MIO_YEARS = 2.366771e14

    @staticmethod
    def compute_answer() -> int:
        time.sleep(DeepThought.SEVEN_HALF_MIO_YEARS)
        return 42
```

yeah, I personally don't want my test suite to run 7.5 mio years. So, what do we do?

```
# deep_thought_test.py 
from deep_thought import DeepThought

def test_define_return_value(mocker) -> None:
    # We use the internal python lookup path to the method 
    # as an identifier (from the location it is called)      
    mocker.patch('deep_thought.DeepThought.compute_answer', return_value=12)
    assert DeepThought.compute_answer() == 12
```

---

Two more minor remarks, not directly related to the post:

- A high code coverage (80% - 90%) is a good goal. I personally try to stck around 90-95%. However, 100% coverage is usually not necessary. Simple(!) data items and log-statements can usually be ignored.
- It's a good practice to use a logger, instead of `print`. See [Question 6918493](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918493/in-python-why-use-logging-instead-of-print) for example.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite, the built-in [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html) isn't yet listed, so here it is:

```py
from unittest import mock

print_mock = mock.MagicMock()
with mock.patch("builtins.print", print_mock):
    function()

# MagicMock records how it was called, which assertions can be made on:
assert print_mock.call_count == 1
args, kwargs = print_mock.call_args
assert args[0].startswith('Number ')
```