# How to debug PyDev GAE project on localhost?

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

How does one simply print out a small string or inspect when running the local Google App Engine server out of Eclipse to debug a PyDev GAE project?

I tried solutions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727410/how-do-i-write-to-the-console-in-google-app-engine), but I am not able to find the logs in the local admin console, nor are they appearing in my Eclipse console.

PyDev breakpoints do not seem to be hit either, even when I use "Debug As.."

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Nevermind.... I have no idea why, but after trying to run it under Debug mode a few more times the Debugging perspective finally popped up... I may close this soon.

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

just after the place you want breakpoints. Then use print statement from terminal to print whatever you what to print. You can also use pprint.

Comment: Arghh, please don't... the PyDev visual debugger is much nicer... if you want programatic breakpoints in PyDev, you can use the remote debugger: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html (import pydevd;pydevd.settrace() -- if you're inside PyDev you can do pydevd|Ctrl+Space for a template completion which will add that along with the sys.path addition to make sure it's found).